# undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Данная проблема очень часто встречается, однако не могу никак ее решить. 
Речь идет о ruby on rails.

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :product_shop, optional: true
 end

class ProductShop < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :products
end
```

на данную строчку компилятор жалуется:

```
 <td><%= product.product_shop.name %></td>
```

извините за банальный вопрос, но в чем может быть ошибка, никак не могу разобраться...

Comment: В том, что `product.product_shop` нету (равен `nil`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно добавить перед

```
<td><%= product.product_shop.name %></td>
```

проверку на  "nil?"

```
unless product.product_shop.nil?
<td><%= product.product_shop.name %></td>
```

Comment: [Это даже забавно](http://i.imgur.com/MBE4yJX.png).

Comment: @D-side, видимо это таки решило проблему? Answer accepted..

Comment: @vp_arth особенно учитывая то, что добавленный код не выполнится, а просто выведется, прямым текстом. Я скорее поверю, что ТС пришло напоминание от системы, что надо бы принять ответ, и он(а?) принял(а?) тот, что был.